# how to add 2 MySQL columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a mysql search, in which the username can also be searched.
This is my PHP (MySQL) code :

```
SELECT * FROM feed_info WHERE ( first_name LIKE '%$search_content%' OR last_name LIKE '%$search_content%' OR email_id LIKE '%$search_content%' OR feed_area LIKE '%$search_content%' OR feed_date LIKE '%$search_content%')
```

But , when i tried to search the `first name` and  `last name` both, like *John Dalton* , it shows no result. I could find the problem that i was only searching `first name` *OR* `last name` . But can't find a way to add those 2 columns. 
So, i want a way that `first name` *and* `last name` can be searched.
For ex. 
When someone searches *John Dalton* , it should show a result

Comment: Thats usual behavior , `LIKE '%$search_content%'` meaning the column should have `John Dalton` and may be other characters before and after that. Check mysql full text search.

Comment: Can you please more clarify your question? With some samole data of your table and result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%$search_content%'
```

i.e;

`WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE 'John Dalton'`

Does this help.?

Comment: The answer is right, but it is working with `LIKE` instead of `=` , `CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%$search_content%' ` . So, you should edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Such thing should be done using fulltext index, using MyIsam tables

```
ALTER TABLE feed_info ADD FULLTEXT(first_name, last_name);
SELECT * FROM feed_info WHERE MATCH(first_name, last_name) AGAINST('John Dalton');
```

Answer (score 0):

One small step ahead is to add the case, where the First Name and Last Name is asked for:

```
SELECT * 
FROM feed_info 
WHERE ( first_name LIKE '%$search_content%' 
     OR last_name LIKE '%$search_content%' 
     OR email_id LIKE '%$search_content%' 
     OR feed_area LIKE '%$search_content%' 
     OR feed_date LIKE '%$search_content%'
     OR LOWER(first_name) + ' ' + LOWER(last_name) = LOWER('$search_content') )
```

This is what I think you asked for. But you still won't be able to search for i.e. last name and email.

Comment: Try this corrected code, notice this has now to be an exact match not regarding chars upper case or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM feed_info where
MATCH (
first_name,last_name,email_id,feed_area,feed_date
)
AGAINST ('$search_content' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

This query is used for mysql full text search.

Change the table engine to InnoDB if this query not working
In Phpmyadmin write this command!

```
ALTER TABLE feed_info ENGINE=InnoDB;
```